# No route matches [GET] "/password_resets"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails. I am creating twitter like clone app. I am adding forgot password functionality to my app. After following the steps from the internet. I am getting routing error. I tried all the possible ways to solve it. But it still shows the same. I tried rake route command and I think there is no problem with the routes.

```
Rake routes:

    password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)          password_resets#create
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format) password_resets#edit
     password_reset PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)      password_resets#update
     cancel_request PUT    /requests/:id/cancel(.:format)      

     edit.html.erb

<h1>Reset Password</h1>

//here I tried changing to password_resets_path still the same error occurs.

<%= form_for @user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class='error_messages'>
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class='actions'><%= f.submit 'Update password' %></div>
<% end %>

password_reset controller:

def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  user.send_password_reset if user
  flash[:notice] = 'E-mail sent with password reset instructions.'
  redirect_to new_session_path
end


def edit
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
end


def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hour.ago
    flash[:notice] = 'Password reset has expired'
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path
  elsif @user.update(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Password has been reset!'
    redirect_to new_session_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password)
  end
```

//invokes password_reset controller

<%= link_to "Forgot_password?", password_resets_path %>

I found similar questions on stackoverflow but none answers my question. Tried all the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with my wrong path specified new_password_reset is the correct one in the case of password_resets_path